# launch systemd service within OCI container (runc)

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, container, systemctl

Currently, I am trying to launch systemd service (avahi-daemon) within RUNC container and all of my attempts were failed. I faced several articles for the same task but for [the docker solution](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/) and [one more](https://forums.docker.com/t/systemctl-status-is-not-working-in-my-docker-container/9075/4). Does anybody have a successful experience with the same task?

This is my config.json:

```
{
"ociVersion": "1.0.0-rc1",
"platform": {
    "os": "linux",
    "arch": "arm"
},
"process": {
    "terminal": false,
    "user": {
        "uid": 0,
        "gid": 0
    },
    "args": [
           "/bin/systemctl", "start", "avahi-daemon"
    ],
    "env": [
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
        "TERM=xterm"
    ],
    "cwd": "/",
    "capabilities": {
            "bounding": [
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "effective": [
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "inheritable": [
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "permitted": [
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "ambient": [
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ]
    },
    "rlimits": [
        {
            "type": "RLIMIT_NOFILE",
            "hard": 1024,
            "soft": 1024
        }
    ],
    "noNewPrivileges": true
},
"root": {
    "path": "rootfs",
    "readonly": false
    },
"hostname": "runc",
"mounts": [
    {
        "destination": "/proc",
        "type": "proc",
        "source": "proc"
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev",
        "type": "tmpfs",
        "source": "tmpfs",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "strictatime",
            "mode=755",
            "size=65536k"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev/pts",
        "type": "devpts",
        "source": "devpts",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "newinstance",
            "ptmxmode=0666",
            "mode=0620",
            "gid=5"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev/shm",
        "type": "tmpfs",
        "source": "shm",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "nodev",
            "mode=1777",
            "size=65536k"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev/mqueue",
        "type": "mqueue",
        "source": "mqueue",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "nodev"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/sys",
        "type": "sysfs",
        "source": "sysfs",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "nodev",
            "ro"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "type": "cgroup",
        "source": "cgroup",
        "options": [
            "ro"
        ]
    }
],
"linux": {
    "resources": {
        "devices": [
            {
                "allow": false,
                "access": "rwm"
            }
        ]
    },
    "namespaces": [
        {
            "type": "network"
        },
        {
            "type": "ipc"
        },
        {
            "type": "uts"
        },
        {
            "type": "mount"
        }
    ],
    "maskedPaths": [
        "/proc/kcore",
        "/proc/latency_stats",
        "/proc/timer_stats",
        "/proc/sched_debug"
    ],
    "readonlyPaths": [
        "/proc/asound",
        "/proc/bus",
        "/proc/fs",
        "/proc/irq",
        "/proc/sys",
        "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
    ]
}
```

This config file releases an error: **"Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory"**.

During my attempts I have tried to:

1. Assign capabilities CAP_SYS_ADMIN to the container;
2. Execute "/sbin/init" binary at the container startup and got an error: **"Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn."**;
3. The init file is a symbolic link to "/lib/systemd/systemd", so I also have tried to use this script directly and also got an error: **"Trying to run as user instance, but the system has not been booted with systemd."**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of the config.json file for the systemd within runc:

```
{
"ociVersion": "1.0.0-rc1",
"platform": {
    "os": "linux",
    "arch": "arm"
},
"process": {
    "terminal": false,
    "user": {
        "uid": 0,
        "gid": 0
    },
    "args": [
        "/sbin/init"
    ],
    "env": [
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
        "TERM=xterm"
    ],
    "cwd": "/",
    "capabilities": {
            "bounding": [
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_CHOWN",
                    "CAP_SETGID",
                    "CAP_SETUID",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_MAC_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_CHROOT",
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "effective": [
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_CHOWN",
                    "CAP_SETGID",
                    "CAP_SETUID",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_MAC_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_CHROOT",
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "inheritable": [
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_CHOWN",
                    "CAP_SETGID",
                    "CAP_SETUID",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_MAC_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_CHROOT",
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "permitted": [
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_CHOWN",
                    "CAP_SETGID",
                    "CAP_SETUID",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_MAC_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_CHROOT",
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ],
            "ambient": [
                    "CAP_KILL",
                    "CAP_CHOWN",
                    "CAP_SETGID",
                    "CAP_SETUID",
                    "CAP_NET_RAW",
                    "CAP_MAC_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN",
                    "CAP_SYS_CHROOT",
                    "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                    "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE"
            ]
    },
    "rlimits": [
        {
            "type": "RLIMIT_NOFILE",
            "hard": 1024,
            "soft": 1024
        }
    ],
    "noNewPrivileges": true
},
"root": {
    "path": "rootfs",
    "readonly": false
    },
"hostname": "runc",
"mounts": [
    {
        "destination": "/proc",
        "type": "proc",
        "source": "proc",
        "options": [
                "nosuid",
                "noexec",
                "nodev"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev",
        "type": "tmpfs",
        "source": "tmpfs",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "strictatime",
            "mode=755"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev/pts",
        "type": "devpts",
        "source": "devpts",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "newinstance",
            "ptmxmode=0666",
            "mode=0620",
            "gid=5"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev/shm",
        "type": "tmpfs",
        "source": "shm",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "nodev",
            "mode=1777",
            "size=65536k"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/dev/mqueue",
        "type": "mqueue",
        "source": "mqueue",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "nodev"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/sys",
        "type": "sysfs",
        "source": "sysfs",
        "options": [
            "nosuid",
            "noexec",
            "nodev"
        ]
    },
    {
        "destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "type": "bind",
        "source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
        "options": [
            "rbind",
            "ro"
        ]
    }
],
"linux": {
    "resources": {
        "devices": [
            {
                "allow": false,
                "access": "rwm"
            }
        ]
    },
    "namespaces": [
        {
            "type": "pid"
        },
        {
            "type": "network"
        },
        {
            "type": "ipc"
        },
        {
            "type": "uts"
        },
        {
            "type": "mount"
        }
    ],
    "maskedPaths": [
        "/proc/kcore",
        "/proc/latency_stats",
        "/proc/timer_stats",
        "/proc/sched_debug"
    ],
    "readonlyPaths": [
        "/proc/asound",
        "/proc/bus",
        "/proc/fs",
        "/proc/irq",
        "/proc/sys",
        "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

systemd services do not run standalone – you can only start them if your pid 1 (init) is systemd. In containers, that requires using a pid namespace in addition to what you already have.

(In other words, systemctl doesn't actually read and execute those .service files *at all* – it only asks pid 1 to start the corresponding daemon.)

In general, I'd say your runC setup already duplicates systemd's built-in features (ProtectHome=, CapabilityBoundingSet=, etc.) But if you *do* want to run the daemon in a dedicated container, you only have two options:

1. Run the container with a new PID namespace, with systemd as its main process, and *have* that systemd instance start avahi-daemon. (systemd-nspawn may work better than runC.)
2. Configure the container to launch /usr/bin/avahi-daemon directly, without involving systemctl or the avahi-daemon.service files at all.

Comment: Okay, I will try the first varian (with dedicated pid namespace) and report you in 12 hours.
About nspawn, I absolutely agree with you, but I have to use runc.